# Developing a rich internet application

Tags: .net, php, ajax, apache-flex, iis

I have been a desktop developer for a few years mostly doing object oriented stuff. I am trying to branch out into web development, and as a hobby project trying to put a web application together. I have been reading quite alot of information, but I still can't seem to decide on the path to take and would really like some advice. Basically, I want to build something like this:

http://mon.itor.us/

I have found this as well:

http://www.trilancer.com/jpolite/#t1

But so far it is of little use as I am trying to grasp Javascript. I have been using visual studio for that, is that a good IDE for this tye of thing or should I try expression blend?
Jpolite seems to do everything with javascript, which seems kind of cool, but I if I want to make a chart inside a widget that connects to a database, do I need something more? Is this where ASP.NET comes in? 
I am familiar with .NET, but if I use ASP.NET for my website, do I have to host it on IIS and windows server as opposed to Apache since mono is still being ironed out? Because that would cost more, so would PHP be a better choice?
Also, for charting these guys as well as google seem to use flex:

http://www.google.com/finance

I have found this:

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/javascript-chart-alternatives/

Would that be sufficient to implement something like google fiance purely in javascript or is there a good reason they use flex?

SOrry for the long post but I was trying to be as detailed as possible. Thanks.

Comment: The google chart API is a nice, light-weight, image-based chart generation service you might consider looking in to. http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ .  If you want to display several charts on a single page, image-based charts are your best bet.  Javascript and flash/flex/etc. will put a lot of load on the browser if you want to show more than maybe 4 graphs on a page.

Comment: Yeah but with good chart you have to sen info to google and back, and if chart is real time that's alot of updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trend, in my experience, is going away from Flex towards Javascript.

That doesn't mean there isn't a place for Flex or that Flex is bad. It just means that 5+ years ago Flex could do lots that you couldn't do (or do well) in Javascript. Nowadays there is far less you can't do in Javascript. Video and music are better done in Flash/Flex (although HTML5 is getting video but that's a long way away from mass adoption in browser share terms).

You probably want to look at some of the "rich" Javascript libraries like YUI, Smartclient or ExtJS. These libraries seek to mimic desktop apps and have a rich gallery of UI widgets to use.

Google Charts is good. I've used it on Web apps. The advantage of Flex-based charting is that you can do more interactive charts.

Comment: Yes but you'll note I said wide browser support and IE6 is still a stubborn ~5-10%

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking at prototype and jQuery. Assuming I make my widgets, how do I connect them to a database and handle postbacks, do I need a web framework for that? Lots of people recommend Django, but since I am familiar with .NET I thought about going the ASP.NET route. The only problem is I don't want to pay Microsoft for IIS, etc.

Comment: I have found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97006/asp-net-mvc-vs-django-which-framework-should-i-learn
but it is from a year ago. So basically, Django vs PHP vs ASP.NET what are the advantages of each, and hosting wise, do I have to use mono for .NET if I want to host on Apache, otherwise I have to pay for an IIS license?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the criteria I would consider for the **UI**:

1. Browser compatibility - Not all browsers/platforms have Flash support (i.e. iPhone) but you can (usually) expect Flash functionality to operate the same across browsers/platforms (unlike Javascript). Also, admin restrictions sometimes limit the ability to install Flash.
2. Ease of development - Flex is very easy and there are many 3rd party libraries available.
3. Load time - I expect load times to be longer when using Flex (see Mint.com or Picnik.com).

If you have a complex UI and can assume your users meet the requirements to run Flash, I would recommend Flex.

If you need a simpler UI that needs to work for users that don't support Flash, I would recommend Javascript.

I've made this a **wiki** for others to add criteria.

Comment: You also could take a look at GWT - Google Web Toolkit.

Comment: So if I were to have many widgets loading different charts, as for example http://mon.itor.us guys do, would it be better performance wise to create those charts in Javascript as opposed to flex? Are javascript libraries powerful enough to develop those charts? Like I said, is there a reason google does it in flex as opposed to Javascript?

Thanks.